# Prove that this language is NP-Hard

Tags: np-hard, satisfiability, counting

Given
$$\mathrm{\#3SAT} = \{ (w, y) \mid  w\text{ is a $\mathrm{3SAT}$ instance with at least $y$ satisfying assignments}\}\,,$$
prove that $\mathrm{\#3SAT}$ is NP-Hard.

I am currently stuck with this one.

Basically $\mathrm{\#3SAT}$ is the counting version of $\mathrm{3SAT}$ and to me it is seems clear that establishing membership in the language is more complex than establish the classic $\mathrm{3SAT}$ membership.

I'm trying to reason through the prover-verifier paradigm: let's say you have a $\mathrm{3SAT}$ instance, now suppose the certificate for that instance is $n$ bits. It is obvious that the certificate for the same instance but translated into $\mathrm{\#3SAT}$ with let's say $y=10$ would be at least $10n$ bits.  So if the first can be examined in time $t$ then the second will take at least $10t$ and so on. However I am not satisfied with this reasoning, it seems  incomplete and superficial. I would greatly appreciate your advice on how to proceed with this proof. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you're trying to prove that $\#\mathrm{3SAT}$ is in $\mathrm{NP}$. Since $\#\mathrm{3SAT}$ is $\mathrm{\#P}$-complete, and $\mathrm{\#P}$ seems to be harder than anything in the polynomial hierarchy, it's very unlikely that $\#\mathrm{3SAT}\in\mathrm{NP}$.

The error in your attempted proof is that your certificate doesn't have polynomial length. A satisfying assignment has length $\Theta(|x|)$ (the formula can't have more variables than its length, but it could be of the form $(x_1\lor x_2\lor x_3) \land (x_4\lor x_5\lor x_6) \land\dots$). The number $y$ could have any value between zero and $2^{|y|}-1$, so your certificate has length about $|x|2^{|y|}$, which is exponential in the input size.

However, the question asks you to prove that it's $\mathrm{NP}$-hard, not that it's $\mathrm{NP}$-complete. You just need to prove that there's a polynomial-time reduction from some $\mathrm{NP}$-complete problem to $\#\mathrm{3SAT}$.

Comment: thanks for the answer. What about this sketch: a NTM can decide membership to 3SAT in polynomial time. Then to decide membership in #3SAT it will take a polynomial expansion on the time implied to decide 3SAT.

Comment: @Yamar69 You're supposed to be reducing problems to $\mathrm{\#3SAT}$, not designing algorithms for $\mathrm{\#3SAT}$.

Comment: David Richerby i know but that is the hard part for me :( can you give me a direction?

Comment: Not being rude, but I'm not sure you do know. You started off trying to prove $\mathrm{\#3SAT}\in\mathrm{NP}$. I said don't do that; reduce an $\mathrm{NP}$-complete problem to it. Then you tried to produce an algorithm for $\mathrm{\#3SAT}$ and I said don't do that; reduce an $\mathrm{NP}$-complete problem to it. It doesn't seem to me that you've spent any time trying to actually reduce an $\mathrm{NP}$-complete problem to $\mathrm{\#3SAT}$. It's only eight minutes since I last told you to do that and you showed no evidence of having tried to do it before then.

Comment: One last question, I noticed that you have edited your answer by adding a comment on the length of the certificate. I understand what you wrote but it seems to me that it is correct only if you take into consideration the space of all possible certificates. Basically what I was saying was this: if you have an instance of # 3SAT with y = 10, The certificate that must be given as a meal to the verifier must contain only 10 different distributions of variables that make the input belonging to # 3SAT(10) and therefore it will be only 10 times larger than the 3SAT's one.

Comment: If you only talk about one instance, _any_ length certificate is polynomial. For example, suppose you have an instance $(x,y)$ and a certificate of length $238762$. Then the length of the certificate is given by the polynomial $p(x,y)=0x+0y+238762$. It only makes sense to say "polynomial length" when you consider all instances. In that case, your certificates have length up to $c|x|2^{|y|}$ for some constant $c$, and that's not polynomial. But you are correct that, if you consider the problem "3SAT instances that have at least ten satisfying assignments" then...

Comment: ... $c|x|2^{10}$ is indeed a polynomial in $x$, so you have proven that "3SAT instances that have at least ten satisfying assignments" is in $\mathrm{NP}$.

Answer (score 3):

The subset for $y = 1$ is 3SAT, which is NP-complete (thus NP-hard); the full set can't be easier...